# Issues with CSS(Small but can't figure it out)

Tags: css

My code is the following:

```
wrapper, wrapper2, content, footer, nav { 
    display: block;
}

html {
    width: 100%;
    height:100%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    background-image:url('../images/gdmm.jpg');
    font-family: 'TitilliumWeb-ExtraLight';
    font-weight:900;
}
body{
    margin:0;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'TitilliumWeb-SemiBold';
  src: url('../TTfont/TitilliumWeb-SemiBold.eot');
  src: local("Grandesign Regular"), url("../TTfont/TitilliumWeb-SemiBold.ttf") format("truetype"); /* non-IE */

  font-family: 'TitilliumWeb-ExtraLight';
  src: url('../TTfont/TitilliumWeb-ExtraLight.eot');
  src: local("Grandesign Regular"), url("../TTfont/TitilliumWeb-ExtraLight.ttf") format("truetype"); /* non-IE */
}

h1 {
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 32px;
    margin-left:auto;
    border-bottom: 1px dashed rgb(221, 221, 221);
    font-weight: 300;
    line-height: 1.4;
    padding: 2px 25px;
    font-family: 'TitilliumWeb-SemiBold';
}

h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
    font-family: "Titillium Web","Source Sans Pro",Helvetica,Arial,serif;
}

#pagewrap{
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#content{
    width:1024px;
    height:768px;
    border-width:5px;
    margin-top:100px;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    word-wrap:break-word;
    background: rgba(252, 252, 255, 0.8);
    overflow:hidden;
    box-shadow: 10px 10px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    word-wrap:break-word;
}

#contentinner{
    width:980px;
    height: 600px;
    background-color: rgb(252, 252, 255);
    margin-top:30px;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    box-shadow: 10px 10px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    word-wrap:break-word;
}

#text{
    font-size: 1.2rem;
    font-weight: 300;
    line-height: 1.6;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    word-wrap:break-word;
}

#navwrapper{
    width: 100%;
    height:50px;
    background-color:#005b96;
    padding:0;
    text-align: center;
    float:none;
    margin:0;
    text-decoration: none;
}

#navonderwrap{
    width: 100%;
    height:30px;
    background-color:#FFFFFF;
    padding:0;
    text-align: center;
    float:none;
    margin:auto;
}


nav{
    display: inline-block;
    overflow: hidden;
    word-spacing: 1em;
    text-align: center;
    margin:auto;
}

#navonder{
    display: inline-block;
    overflow: hidden;
    word-spacing: 1em;
    text-align: center;
    margin:auto;
}


nav ul{
    margin-right:20px;
    padding:0;
    width:auto;
}

nav ul li{
    display:table-cell;
    margin-right:20px;
}

nav li
{
    display:inline;
}

nav li a
{
    font-family:Arial;
    font-size:14px;
    float:left;
    padding:0px;
    border-bottom:1px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

nav li a:hover {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    background-color:#FFF;
    padding-bottom:10px;
}
```

My issue is that when you hover on the menu it pushes the entire thing down all I want is it to look as if it has the same color as the one below, I can't figure out why.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In it's default state the `<a>` has no padding, but in it's hover state it has `padding-bottom: 10px;`.

In order to make it look like it joins the white bar below, you'll need to add:

```
nav ul {
  margin-bottom: 0; /* to reset the default */
}

nav li a {
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 14px;
  float: left;
  /* padding: 0px; REMOVE */
  padding-bottom: 10px; /* ADD */
  border-bottom: 1px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

nav li a:hover {
  /*display: block; REMOVE (unnecessary) */
  /* float: left; REMOVE (because it's already set on default state) */
  background-color: #FFF;
  /* padding-bottom: 10px; REMOVE (because it's already set on default state */
```

}

Comment: It worked!! thanks!! Although it's positioned strangely now it's all the way up the top of my screen. Why is this so? http://davidhaile.nl/test/

Comment: What's all the way up the top of your screen?

Comment: My nav bar it's like pushed up but I changed it although there's now a small opening between the two bars if you can see it on my site now.

Comment: Nevermind it updated very slowly :S but thank you so much!! It's fixed now :D

Answer (score 2):

this comes from the padding-bottom:10px you apply.

In addition to that you say display the link as a block and you make it float... so you can remove the display:block; it is useless in that case.

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't help :/
EDIT: Didn't realise you ment the padding but thanks that was it!

Answer (score 0):

```
nav li a {
     padding: 10px; //Add
}

nav li a:hover {
   background-color: #FFFFFF;
   display: block;
   float: left;
   padding-bottom: 10px; /// Remove this
```

}

Remove `padding bottom`

Comment: Thanks! But how can I enlarge the box that shows around the hover so that it'll blend with the white bar under it?

Comment: You'll have to give padding by default then highlight(change bg color) on :hover

Comment: Sorry I don't get what you mean can you example it somehow?

Comment: Thanks but there's a small opening between both bars how do I close this gap?